# enabling intellitrace with visual web developer 2010 express

Tags: visual-studio, intellitrace

I am using Visual studio web developer 2010 and want to know how to enable intellitrace on it.

Thanks
Supraja J

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intellitrace is available only on Ulitmate verison of Visual studio. Visual web developer comes only in express edition, so intellitrace is not supposed to be avialable there.

http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/product-comparison

Comment: oh dear ! i am doing my azure project and looking for good debugging tools !

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Intellitrace is only available in Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate.

Comment: so with web developer 2010 there is no hope of debugging azure except the debug mode ?

Comment: @SuprajaJayakumar I think the phase no hope is a little wrongly placed. Most of us have managed for years without intellitrace